# How to check how many time a car is parked on

Tags: mysql, sql, database, reporting

I need a report of which cars (license plates) are parked in and when.

This is an example of my table.

```
id  lic_plate   datetime                   lane    
_________________________________________________
10  1234-JM     2022-10-07 12:24:33        IN    
11  1234-JM     2022-10-07 12:29:57        OUT
12  5678-PC     2022-10-07 15:14:17        IN
```

So when I query which are those who are parked more than - for instance - 1hour, the result Now (2022-10-07 15:14:17) should be "5678-PC".

I have tried:

```
SELECT lic_plate, COUNT(*) AS result
FROM table
GROUP BY lic_plate
HAVING COUNT(lane='IN') AND COUNT(lane='OUT')
```

But I can't figure out where I insert the HOUR query. And it seems to me that this kind of solution will have some "hidden" flaws.

What will be the best approach?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: One approach would be to outer join the table to itself. One copy of the table would be restricted to lane In, and the other copy restricted to lane out. You can join using the lic_plate. Then you can subtract the in time from the out time, if both exist.

Comment: `COUNT(lane='IN')` should be `SUM(lane='IN')`. `COUNT()` counts the number of non-null values, but `lane='IN'` will never be null unless `lane` is null.

Comment: I'm confused of what you are trying to do with `HAVING COUNT(lane='IN') AND COUNT(lane='OUT')`.. that doesn't seem to do anything. If you change that to `HAVING SUM(lane='IN') AND SUM(lane='OUT')`, you'll only get `1234-JM` as result.

Comment: You also need to clarify your condition, how about cars that already `OUT` but the condition of _"park more than 1 hour from now"_ is valid, should those be returned in result too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select   max(id) as id  
        ,lic_plate  
        ,max(datetime)                 as datetime
        ,timediff(now(),max(datetime)) as time_parked
from     t
group by lic_plate
having   count(*)%2 != 0
```

| id | lic_plate | datetime | time_parked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 5678-PC | 2022-10-07 15:14:17 | 69:26:12 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5sZY5cDl)

Comment: Is it possible to show only the cars that are parked over 1 (one) two (2) or more hours? I have tried to do it with the WHERE clause but there seems to me a problem. I think the solution is to get and filter it by the time_parked but I don't know how to grab it like "WHERE @time_parked >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR"... something is not logically correct!

Comment: @JosédeMatos Please open a new question for that (and give valid data sample + required results).

Answer (score 1):

We check the time difference between the current date and time and `datetime`. We count how many records we have per car and if we have even numbers of records we filter the results as we know the car is out already.

```
select  id  
       ,lic_plate   
       ,datetime
       ,time_parked
from    (
        select  *
                ,count(*) over(partition by lic_plate) as chk
                ,timediff(now(),datetime) as time_parked
        from    t
        ) t
where   chk%2 != 0
```

| id | lic_plate | datetime | time_parked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 5678-PC | 2022-10-07 15:14:17 | 00:29:58 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/g7IixcUk)

Comment: Unfortunately the MySQL version is 5.7  and with no chance to change it. Like in Fiddle, when I change to MySQL 5.7 I obtain an error as in my machine "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by lic_plate) as chk
                ,timediff(now(),datetime) as tim' at line 7".

Comment: @JosédeMatos I posted another solution that will work with MySQL 5.7.